# Maven: compiling with all dependencies in one Jar

Tags: maven-2

in pom of a project, i have added dependency with scope compile . which is a jar file which contains some class file and jar's as well. my current java file needs internal jars of dependent jar to compile.

But maven compile goal returning compilation error . :banghead:

All the jar's needed to compile are in the single jar file which is added in dependency.............................

Please help me!

**my pom:**

```
<project>
  <!-- ... -->
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>eagle</groupId>
      <artifactId>zkui</artifactId>
      <version>360LTS</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>./src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>./target/classes</outputDirectory>
    <finalName>${project.groupId}-${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

**error:**

> package org.zkoss.zk.ui does not exist
>   this package org.zkoss.zk.ui is in jar
>   file zkex.jar which is in dependency
>   jar eagle:zkui:360LTS jar file

Please Help ME!!!! :jumpingjoy:

Advance Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess you could

- use [`dependency:unpack`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html) to unpack the jars to target/lib or so (before compile)
- deactivate [`compiler:compile`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html) by excluding everything

  ```
  <excludes>
      <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
  </exclude>
  ```
- use [`antrun:run`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/run-mojo.html) with the ant [`javac`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) task to compile the sources, something like this (bind the execution to phase `compile`):

  ```
  <target>
      <javac srcdir="${project.build.sourceDirectory}"
             destdir="${project.build.outputDirectory}">
          <classpath>
              <pathelement path="${maven.compile.classpath}"/>
              <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/lib">
                  <include name="**/*.jar"/>
              </fileset>
          </classpath>
      </javac> 
  </target>
  ```

However, while that would help you *compile* your application, it would not help you *run* or *deploy* your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the  element to do this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>groep.does.not.matter</groupId>
      <artifactId>neither-does-artifactId</artifactId>
      <version>and.nor-does-version</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>system</scope>
      <systemPath>${project.baseDir}/lib/jarname.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

where the jar you need to reference (and have in your classpath) is lib/jarname.jar, and the lib directory is in the root of your project.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're actually not using the proper dependencies. ZK actually have Maven repositories as described [here](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Installation_Guide/Setting_up_IDE/Maven/Use_ZK_Maven_Repository).

You need to check which dependencies you need. For example for zkex, you would need something like:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
        <artifactId>zkex</artifactId>
        <version>${zk.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

You will also need to add the ZK Maven repositories:

```
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>zk repository</id>
            <url>http://mavensync.zkoss.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
        <!-- If Using ZK EE or ZK PE Respository (not evaluation version), you need to add login info into ~/.m2/settings.xml -->
        <repository>
            <id>ZK PE Evaluation</id>
            <url>http://mavensync.zkoss.org/zk/pe-eval</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>ZK EE Evaluation</id> 
            <url>http://mavensync.zkoss.org/zk/ee-eval</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

Good luck! :-)